# Proving that the Bellman-Ford algorithm contains negative circuit

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Let $D=(V,B), n=|V|$ be a directed graph. Then the graph contains a circuit of negative length from $s$ if and only if $f_n(v) \neq f_{n-1}(v),$ where $v \in V,$ and $f_k(v)=$min$\{l(P)|P$ is an $s-v$ walk traversing at most $k$ arcs }.

I do not understand what a $s-v$ walk means and what is the meaning of the function $f_n$.

Can somebody help me prove the two directions of the above statement  ? Many thanks.

Comment: An $s-v$ walk is just a sequence of vertices and edges, where the sequence starts with vertex $s$, ends with vertex $v$ and for each edge $e$ (say from $u$ to $v$) in the sequence, we have $u$ to the left of $e$ and $v$ to the right of $e$ in the sequence.

Comment: $f_k(v)$ picks out the minimum length walk from $s$ to $v$ that uses at most $k$ edges